# Merging storyboards xcode 5

Tags: xcode, storyboard

A very quick question.

I've created 2 storyboards main.storyboard and item.storyboard.

I'd originally thought keeping them separated made more sense in terms of organisation however I'm starting to think they'd be better as a single file.

I'm wondering if there's a preferred way to merge item.storyboard into main.storyboard from the xcode tool. I was looking into using filemerge initially but there might be a better way.

Comment: I've never heard of any tool like this. TBH though it would probably be easier to just copy paste everything from one into the other.

Comment: Storyboards are just XML files, so you might be able to merge them outside Xcode if you're good at XML.  But, even then, it might still be a copy/paste effort with some cleanup and tweaking.

Comment: yeah that's why i looked into the filemerge tool but upon reviewing the merge I thought it too tricky